# file/Multi-channel descriptor (2) passed to $fclose is not valid

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, fclose

This is a follow up question to one posted on Feb. 5. I did not know how to follow-up that thread, hence this new question.

I have updated test bench attached. It contains $fwrite etc. as suggested.
Now getting warning:

> file/Multi-channel descriptor (2) passed to $fclose in not valid

The AA2.txt file is empty. Used $fwrite (instead of $fmonitor) and it works but with same warning. Should I just ignore the warning ? I also tried to use "reset" (SEE CODE) based on the status of a DUT output signal (negedge ASM_FLAG) which goes from 1 to 0 at the end of simulation, to stop writing to file, but reset is always 1 so no output. It seems like the simulation has not started.  Can you explain?

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

// Create Date:   16:57:34 12/04/2014
// Design Name:   ADC_SAMPLE
// Module Name:   C:/Xilinx131/SOC/SOC501V2/ADC_SAMPLE_tb.v
// Project Name:  SOC501V2
//
// Verilog Test Fixture created by ISE for module: ADC_SAMPLE for review with Honeywell
// 
// Revision 0.01 - File Created

module ADC_SAMPLE_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg CLK;
    reg ASM_SEL;
    reg [11:0] ADC_BUS;
    reg [7:0] ADC_Wait_Time;

    // Outputs
    wire [7:0] ASM_HB;
    wire [7:0] ASM_LB;
    wire AS_SConv;
    wire AS_OE;
    wire ASM_FLAG;
    wire [3:0] S;

    parameter PERIOD = 100;
    parameter real DUTY_CYCLE = 0.5;
    parameter OFFSET = 0;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    ADC_SAMPLE uut (
        .CLK(CLK), 
        .ASM_SEL(ASM_SEL), 
        .ADC_BUS(ADC_BUS), 
        .ADC_Wait_Time(ADC_Wait_Time), 
        .ASM_HB(ASM_HB), 
        .ASM_LB(ASM_LB), 
        .AS_SConv(AS_SConv), 
        .AS_OE(AS_OE), 
        .ASM_FLAG(ASM_FLAG), 
        .S(S)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        CLK = 0;
        ASM_SEL = 1;
        ADC_BUS = 12'hABC;
        ADC_Wait_Time = 4;
    end

   initial    
    begin
        #OFFSET;
        forever
        begin
            CLK = 1'b1;
            #(PERIOD-(PERIOD*DUTY_CYCLE)) CLK = 1'b0;
            #(PERIOD*DUTY_CYCLE);
        end
    end 

    initial begin
        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        // Add stimulus here
        #200 ASM_SEL=1;
        #150 ASM_SEL=0;

    end

    integer h1;
    reg reset;

    initial begin
    reset = 0;
    @(negedge ASM_FLAG) reset = 1;//at completion of sim, ASM_FLAG goes 0;
    end

    initial begin
    $display("ADC_SAMPLE_tb simulator output");
    $display ("h1,CLK, ASM_SEL,ASM_HB,ASM_LB,AS_SConv, AS_OE, ASM_FLAG,S");
    end

    initial begin
    h1 = $fopen("AA2.txt");//did not work as a seperate init/begin block..
    end

    always @ (posedge CLK)
    begin
    repeat (10)
//  while (reset == 0)
    begin
    $fwrite(h1,"%d,%b,%b,%b,%h,%h,%b,%b,%b,%h,\n",
                h1,reset,CLK, ASM_SEL,/* ADC_BUS,ADC_Wait_Time,*/ASM_HB,ASM_LB,
                AS_SConv, AS_OE, ASM_FLAG,
                S); 
    end
    $fclose (h1);

    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep closing the file on every CLK posedge in the `always` block.  Don't do that.  In your case, there is no need to even call `$fclose` because it will be closed when the simulation terminates.